# Series Problem in Stewart's Calculus Book

Tags: calculus

Problem is simple. And the book suggests that we hould solve by steps :

*Problem* : Show that $$ \pi = \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{8^n} \bigg( \frac{2}{3n+1} + \frac{1}{3n+2} \bigg) $$

(a) $$ \int^\frac{1}{2}_0 \frac{dx}{x^2-x+1} =
\int^\frac{1}{2}_0 \frac{dx}{
(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}
\tan^{-1} \frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}} \bigg|_0^\frac{1}{2}  =
\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$$

(b) I can not understand (b) step : "Factor $x^3+1$ as a sum of cubes and rewirte (a)-integration"

My try : $$ \frac{1}{3}\bigg[ \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{
-\frac{1}{2}(2x-1) +
\frac{3}{2}}{x^2-x+1}\bigg]=\frac{1}{(1+x)(1-x+x^2)}=\frac{1}{1+x^3}
 $$ $$= 1-x^3 + x^6\cdots = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x^3)^n $$

$$ \frac{1}{3}\ln\ (x+1) - \frac{1}{2} \ln\ (x^2-x+1)
\bigg|_0^\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{3}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty
(-1)^n \frac{x^{3n+1}}{3n+1} \bigg|^\frac{1}{2}_0$$

So log-term appears. How can we derive the formula ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Stewart seems to have in mind is something slightly different. Write $$\frac1{x^2-x+1}=\frac{1+x}{1+x^3}=(1+x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x^3)^n.$$